# pythonで日付列と時刻列を結合してインデックスとしたい

Tags: python

日付  時刻  
0   2015-04-01  00:00:00
1   2015-04-01  00:01:00
2   2015-04-01  00:02:00
3   2015-04-01  00:03:00
4   2015-04-01  00:04:00

上記のようなデータフレームがあるときに、”2015-04-01 00:00:00” 2015-04-01 00:01:00"というように日付と時刻を結合しインデックスとしたいのですが、どのように記載したらよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

日付、時刻 columnのデータがstr型でしたら、単純に結合した後に
Pandas.to_datateime() に渡したらよいのではないでしょうか

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """日付,時刻,データ
2015-04-01,00:00:00,1
2015-04-01,00:01:00,2
2015-04-01,00:02:00,3
2015-04-01,00:03:00,4
2015-04-01,00:04:00,5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

df['日時'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日付'] + ' ' + df['時刻'])
df = df.set_index('日時')
df = df.drop(['日付','時刻'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

**【追記】**

一応、日付と時刻 のデータがdatetime型の場合についても言及しておきます。
その場合も、一度文字列に変換することで同じことを行うことができます。

```
df['日時'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日付'].dt.strftime('%x ') + df['時刻'].dt.strftime('%X'))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この問題は解決できました。